# how to bind data dynamically using datalist and display data look like this

Tags: c#, asp.net

IN first rows have 2 column in first column  display image and 2nd display textcontent. and second rows in first column display first textcontent and then image ..please help ..

Comment: Please clarify your question, I have no idea what you're asking for. Do you have an example of something you've already tried to get working?

Comment: Please provide more information and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please check this   http://www.crmnext.com/product/sales/

Comment: Please Do my Homework type...

Comment: hii DGibbs  i would like to bind data dynamic and display like  crmnext.com/product/sale this page so please help me ...

Comment: @LALBABU That is a very broad request, you need to narrow it down to a specific problem. Have you tried implementing this yourself? Are you facing issues with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Well For binding data on fly what you can do is this 
Create Grid view in your page and give it data Source and in code behind or your C#
do something like this

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand ="SELECT * from Table1" ;
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

And to change the appearance of your Grid-view you can use CSS